# Streaming MPEG TS file via UDP Multicast with given bitrate in C#/.Net Core

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have multiplexed transport stream file which recorded from sattelite DVB-S2 with constant bitrate 38.01 Mbit/sec

I'll try to restream it into my local network:

```
string tsFile = @"E:\dvb\dvb_lib\27.ts";

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tsFile);

        UdpClient outPutUdpClient = new UdpClient { ExclusiveAddressUse=false};

        IPAddress outPutIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.99.239");
        int multicastPort = 1234;

        var localEp = new IPEndPoint(outPutIp, multicastPort);

        outPutUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        outPutUdpClient.Ttl = 3;
        outPutUdpClient.Client.Bind(localEp);

        var mcastAddr = IPAddress.Parse("239.1.1.1");

        outPutUdpClient.Connect(mcastAddr, multicastPort);            
        
        for(int i = 1316; i < bytes.Length; i+=1316) // take 7 ts packets per one UDP packet
        {
            int begin = i-1316;
            int end = i;

            var sendBytes = bytes[begin..end];

            Thread.Sleep(1); <--- NEED Delay 2641 ticks

            try
            {
                outPutUdpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
```

This solution give me ~10 Mbit/sec
If I remove Thread.Sleep, my app push all file in 500 msec (4.3 Gbit/sec)

Some math:
38.01 Mbit/sec - give as 39856373 bit per second.
I send UDP with 7 ts packet in each udp packet. 188 * 7 * 8=10528 bits per packet.
If i want to send udp with 38.01 Mbit/sec I need to send 1 udp packet in every 2641 tick.
But Thread.Sleep can take only 1 millisecond and not less...
I think using Thread sleep is not correct solution for this case.
How can i restream recorded transport stream file with given bitrate in .Net?

**Update1:**
Adding this block gives me +- 38 Mbit/sec on output. But I can't calculate this magic number 60. I'll found it experimentally, starts with 100 and step down and control bandwidth on wireshark at the same time

```
            counter++;               

            if (counter >= 60)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                counter = 0;
            }
```

Also i can extract PCR value from one of the video streams from this ts file
Thats part of this values:

```
15:41:05.0646068
15:41:05.0999771
15:41:05.1352739
15:41:05.1703252
15:41:05.2058182
15:41:05.2407959
15:41:05.2763135
....
```

Can anyone help me to find algo which can calculate delay(this magic number) based on PCR?

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng this article about acquiring timestamps, not about microseconds delay in manage code.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using UDP instead of one of the many transports specifically designed for streaming media?

Comment: @RobertPerry I Am working with UDP, because it is using on DVB broadcasting servers. And I'll try to write my own ts player for testing use.

Comment: I asked because it looks like you’ve got .ts files.. If you stick those into an HLS playlist, you’ll probably be able to just play them back in a browser using something simple like video.js